# why do I keep getting Attribute error in python 3.9

Tags: python

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
alex = turtle.Turtle()
alex.forward(150)
alex.left(90)
alex.forward(75)
turtle.done()
```

that is my code. And the error I keep getting is:

```
File "C:/Users/stevewestmoreland/Documents\turtle.py", line 2, in <module>
    wn = turtle.Screen()
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'turtle' has no attribute 'Screen' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Answer (score 2):

You named your own script `turtle.py`, which shadows the `turtle` module you think you're importing; there can be only one module with a given name, and you stole it from the "real" `turtle`. Use a different name.